# Ubuntu 16.04 Wifi Issues. Possible missing drivers

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, iwlwifi

I've been running Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop for awhile now and all of a sudden wifi stopped working. Under `System Settings > Network` the Wifi interface does not appear. Running `sudo lshw -C network` yields the following:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 78
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ed300000-ed301fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 31
       serial: 10:65:30:19:49:47
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.1-3 ip=10.0.0.198 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:131 memory:ed400000-ed41ffff
```

From googling around, I understand that `network UNCLAIMED` means that my wifi card is not in use by any modules? Or maybe its missing a driver? Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pioj.png) of `System Settings > Software and Updates > Additional Drivers` as well

Also might be worth mentioning that I disabled Secure Boot (I'm not really sure why I did this other than this came up when searching for `dkms`). Any help would be greatly appreciated!!